# Doesn't a test class using MockWebServer require a runner?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockwebserver

I have a very basic question, I'm new to unit testing and I have a test class in which I'm testing Spring WebClient using MockWebServer. All the tests run fine but why don't we need a runner when using MockWebServer? When using Mockito we annotate the class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).

Comment: The `@RunWith` would be required for JUnit 4 but not Junit 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JUnit 4 `Runner` or `Rule` or JUnit Jupiter `Extension` conveniently takes care (among other things) of the test setup, e.g. starting and stopping the `MockWebServer` for you in the background.

You don't have to use a `Runner`/`Rule` or `Extension` for your tests and can start/stop your *test infrastructure* manually as part of `@BeforeAll`/`@AfterAll` or inside the test.

However, this adds boilerplate code to every test that requires this kind of infrastructure and you can delegate this task to a `Runner`/`Rule` or `Extension` if your test library provides one.

In the particular example for `MockWebServer`, you can use [their JUnit 4 rule](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver-junit4), their [JUnit 5 integration](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver-junit5), or perform the start/stop operations for the server on your own.